# using typescript definition file (.d.ts) for typing javascript code doesn't warn about primitive type errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

I have simple js component

> ./component/index.js : `export const t = 'string value';`

it has typescript definition file

> ./component/index.d.ts : `export const t: number;`

Very simple typescript/react project is consuming this component:

> ./demo/index.tsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { t } from '../component';

ReactDOM.render(<>{ t }</>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Expected result**: typescript error indicating that value of 't' is expected to be number but received string instead.

**Actual result**: no errors or warnings from typescript.

[Here](https://github.com/omatviiv/ts-definition-file-test) is small project that reproduces this issue, I tried to make it as minimal as possible, just do:

- `git clone git@github.com:omatviiv/ts-definition-file-test.git`
- `npm i`
- `npm run dev`

I checked the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) but it doesn't help (they mention `12` instead numeric type in the examples which confuses), Also provided there [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useJavaScript=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQIICcsEMCeAMqmMlABYAUuOAlIgN6IBQiiW6IWSNWAdABsSZcswC+zCAgDOURAFtcADwAq5GKUQBeRAEYATM2by4AExBC+qJQAc4WKNO2NWKdNjxFhFADSvFquqk4sxAA) doesn't seem to be useful for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you provide a `d.ts` it uses that as gospel, and flat out ignores any code in your code files.

So in your case `t` is a `number`. So in react `<div>{t}</div>` is totally valid, react will coerce that to display the number so there isn't any type errors expected here.

Comment: 1. React is not the reason. I tried the same by eliminating react from the equation - replaced `./demo/index.tsx` content with `import { t } from '../component'; console.log(t);`  and typescript doesn't complain.

Comment: 2. What you say means that definition files behave differently from ts files because if I add line to index.tsx: `const b: number = 12;` it results in error: __TS2322: Type '12' is not assignable to type 'string'.__
and in the same time this is fine:
__index.js__ `export const t = 12;` 
__index.d.ts__ `export const: string;`

Comment: This is confusing because I thought .d.ts can be used to write typings of the same strictness as directly in the ts files. Turns out it is not, or maybe I'm simply missing some ts config option ?